# User Connectivity Issue in Unix/Oracle 9i

Tags: security, unix, oracle9i

I used to connect oracle db frmo Unix terminal witout providing any password as mentioned below.
sqlplus / and it connects to the data base. Now I am facing an error saying "Invalid Userid and Password".

Can someone please provide any pointers on this. Your inputs are higly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you connect to SQL*Plus using / it means you are using Operating System authentication. Normally this requires your Unix user to be in group "dba" or the equivalent.

[See TFM](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10897/em_manage.htm#ADMQS0361)

You can check your groups like this:

```
$ groups
```

Also, you probably need to connect as sysdba, e.g.

```
sqlplus> CONNECT / AS SYSDBA
```

or AS SYS. Did you forget that?

Another problem can be if the DBA has turned off OS Authentication at the database.

Comment: Thank you, I will try these options.